# Can Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor look for any activity being started?

Tags: android, android-activity, instrumentation, intentfilter, activity-monitor

According to the Android documentation, Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor is able to return an Activity that is being started. That is, you pass it an IntentFilter in its constructor so it knows what it's looking for. My question is, is it possible for ActivityMontior to look for any kind of Activity starting? In other words, is it possible to use ActivityMonitor to return the top most Activity showing on the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ActivityMonitor will wait for any Activity that matches the IntentFilter, which when started will be the top most, unless you are using some flags like [FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP) that may affect this ordering.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've been playing around with Instrumentation but haven't actually gotten it to work at all. How do I even start "scanning" for Activities using ActivityMonitor, do I start a thread? I actually been trying to figure out how to use Instrumentation; I just thought the ActivityMonitor's ability to return Activity objects was what useful.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715397/how-to-test-a-listactivity/6716048#6716048 for an example